# Force render of HTML

Tags: xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I'm using [Xam.Plugins.WebView](https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview) with static HTML on multiple pages of a carousel. I find that when a carousel page first shows a page the HTML takes a while to render and there's an ugly flash. This doesn't happen when using the default Forms WebView but I'm not using that because it doesn't do Javascript integration. Is there a way to trigger a rendering of HTML before it's visible? (Under the covers it's using WkWebView instead of UIWebView, which is what Forms WebView uses.)

Comment: Do you have a try with HybridWebView to realize it ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Comment: @MSFT That's a much simpler control. I'm using it now. But the problem turned out to be the carousel not rendering the control until it was visible.

Comment: Perhaps the size of the image in the carousel is too large to be loaded and displayed in time. You can share some of the code of the html.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Using the debugger, it's clear that the WebView renderer's `OnElementChanged` method isn't called until its containing carousel screen is shown. I'm having a look through the source code to see if I can force it. https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview

Comment: I meant this... https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

Comment: Okey , it seems like the limit of renderer , can not be called before carousel screen is shown.

Comment: That's right. It only adds one screen at a time to the underlying page view controller. It's too much work to fix this so I'll leave it. The flash isn't too bad on a real device.